# extract data from data frame and delete extracted data

Tags: r

i have a data frame with three variables named df. what i want is in "df1" subset df in such a way that the extracted data to no longer exist in the df. it can be done by "subset" but The extracted data will still exist in df.
any help would be appreciated.

```
df<- 

    gender  age     pro
  
       1    22   0.0301  
       2    11   0.0934  
       1    44   0.108   
       2    56   0.0894  
       1    70   0.0444  
       2    33   0.00945 
       1    23   0.00226 
       2    32   0.0258  
       1    12   0.0701  
       2     1   0.0827  
       1    17   0.0657  
       1     9   0.0324  
       2    44   0.00755 
       1    49   0.000456
       2    39   0.0255  
       1    18   0.0828  
       2    31   0.0931  
       1     8 0.0717
 
df1<- subset(df, age > 14 & age< 50 & gender==2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::anti_join` to remove the extracted data from original data.

```
df1<- subset(df90, age > 14 & age< 50 & gender==2)
df90 <- dplyr::anti_join(df90, df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do with base R:

```
df1 <- subset(df, !(age > 14 & age < 50 & gender==2))
```

Output:

```
   gender   age      pro
    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1      1    22 0.0301  
 2      2    11 0.0934  
 3      1    44 0.108   
 4      2    56 0.0894  
 5      1    70 0.0444  
 6      1    23 0.00226 
 7      1    12 0.0701  
 8      2     1 0.0827  
 9      1    17 0.0657  
10      1     9 0.0324  
11      1    49 0.000456
12      1    18 0.0828  
13      1     8 0.0717
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, !(age > 14 & age < 50 & gender==2))
```